# Pushing to origin is rejected after reset soft

Tags: git

I've reset to a commit in my local history and after changing them I wanted to push my changes but it said: "Push to origin rejected".

How can I push my changes to origin?

Comment: Try `git push -f origin <branch-name>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you change the local history by the reset command, the local history will be different with its origin branch, you should use force push instead of the push.

```
git push origin <your_branch_name> --force
```

or

```
git push origin <your_branch_name> -f
```